How to debug macOS app in lldb that takes over keyboard focus?
I am porting an app to macOS that takes over keyboard focus. It is seg faulting and I have no problems attaching lldb and running the program until it hits a breakpoint before entering the function that crashes.
lldb is now waiting for me to step through the program but even if I switch to Terminal.app, I can't use my keyboard because the program being debugged has taken over keyboard focus.
How do I interact with lldb in this circumstance?
I tried setting a new breakpoint on the first line of main.cpp and confirm I have keyboard focus in lldb.
I tried to set up debugserver so I attach to the process remotely on another computer:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Resources/debugserver 192.168.0.100:1234 --attach 1816

I have a dilemma in that I can't run the program directly because it crashes before I can attach to it. It is already running in lldb (1817) with the breakpoint before the crash:
debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:LLDB  PROJECT:lldb-1500.0.404.7
 for arm64.
Attaching to process 1816...
error: failed to attach process 1816: (os/kern) invalid task - process 1816 is already being debugged by pid 1817
Exiting.

I'm not attached (ahem, no pun intended) to debugging remotely.
My preference is to debug locally and have a means to switch keyboard focus back and forth between the app being debugged and lldb.
I am open to ideas of the most effective way to debug an app that crashes during its initialization process.

macOS apps don't usually keep you from switching to another app, even apps that are not fetching UI events at all (e.g. with the spinning beachball) still allow you to switch to another app and interact with it.  If you can't just switch to Terminal by clicking in the Dock, etc. that's unexpected.  Short of figuring out why the app is doing this unfriendly thing, you're going to have a hard time debugging your crash locally.  As to remote debugging, here's a page with some more details on how to do that with lldb: https://lldb.llvm.org/use/remote.html

@JimIngham to clarify - I can switch to Terminal.app - it just won’t capture keyboard input unless I put a breakpoint before the offending function (which I’m out to find). You inspired me to try a different solution and it works and will post the answer.

The solution is to ssh into the computer hosting the process (eg. with an app like Termius) and run lldb on the app you are debugging in the remote terminal. Be sure to ssh in as the same user.
The app in macOS will not be able to takeover keyboard focus of the external device (in my case, an iPadPro) and you will be able to interact and use the debugger (lldb)
Be noted this procedure is not the same as remotely attaching to the process.
The procedure described above is akin to opening up a Terminal.app window on a different machine.
It solves the problem through the use of a completely separate keyboard whose focus cannot be captured by the remote machine.

Remotely running lldb is the simplest way to do this for sure.  You could also (following the instructions I linked to) run debugserver as the remote agent and connect to it with lldb on the second machine.  That's more work but has the advantage that almost all the CPU and memory intensive work goes on in lldb, not debugserver, so debugging doesn't load the target system.  Sometimes that matters, and is worth the trouble, though not in your case...

hmm - there must be something I don’t understand about how debugserver is set up.  perhaps I wasn’t supposed to attempt to attach to an existing macOS process and remove the --attach 1816 argument in the debugserver command line I posted in my original post and use lldb (say on a Linux machine) to start the macOS process, set breakpoints, and debug from there?

You need to run your lldb session on another machine, since that's the only way you are going to keep access to the terminal input to lldb.  You also want to start the session from lldb rather than attaching to a running process, because you want to start the debug session before this bad API is called.  If you run debugserver <program-name> <remote-host> the lldb will start up <program-name> but then halt it when it is about to execute the first instruction.  Then when you connect to it from lldb and continue the program will start running.

Note, one difficulty with debugging remotely is that lldb has to read symbol information from the remote system, and the protocol it uses is not very efficient for this.  It helps if you have a copy of the binary and libraries from the remote system available locally so lldb doesn't have to read them remotely.
